# how to return image url instead of file path

Tags: c#, angularjs, image, url, asp.net-web-api

I am facing an issue when showing uploaded image in browser. 
I get error

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///C:/Office%20Data/dummy/AngularJSAuthentication-master/MyCars/MyCar.API/App_Data/Images/p7.jpeg%20alt=

I wrote the following line of code to store image on server under App_data.

```
File.Path = Url.Content(string.Format("{0}/{1}", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images"), fileName));
```

File path saved in DB as following

```
file:///C:/Sample%20Data/dummy/AngularJSAuthentication-master/MyCars/MyCar.API/App_Data/Images/p7.jpeg
```

**HTML**

```
<img ng-src="{{motor.FileUploads[0].Path}} alt="Description" />
```

After googling i got the reason for this error.

```
Basically i need to return back Image URL instead of file path.
```

**Problem:**
I am not sure how i can return image path back to angular client.

Can someone guide me on it.

Comment: Can you share the <img Html you are using?

Comment: I have updated my question to answer your question. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify the complete physical path, when reference from the browser

```
File.Path = Url.Content(string.Format("~/App_Data/Images/{0}", fileName));
```

this should return the relative URL

Update : well this won't work since you can directly access contents of the app_data folder. you can approach this either of these ways

- move the images out of the app_data folder to like ~/images folder
  and it should work or
- keep the file in the app_data folder but stream the file using
  content/file result action on one of your controllers

bare minimum sample implementation of the second option would look like

```
public class UploadsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Image( string fileName )
    {
        //!validate file name!
        return File( Server.MapPath( $"~/App_Data/{fileName}" ), "image/jpeg" );
    }
}
```

then in the HTML it can be referenced as `<img src="api/uploads/image?filename=temp.jpg" ...`

Comment: In this case it returns "http://localhost:26264/App_Data/Images/p5.jpeg" However,  still browser says "GET http://localhost:26264/App_Data/Images/p5.jpeg%20alt= 404 (Not Found)"  HTTP Error 404.8 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a path in the URL that contains a hiddenSegment section.

Comment: Ah! I forgot that you can't directly access files stored in App_Data folder. in this case you have two options. I will update the answer

Comment: I have setup two projects Web Api and Web. So you meant in your 1st solution is to create /Images folder under Web Project or Web Api project?  fyi: App_Data/Images is under Web Api project. How you udnerstood what i meant here.

Comment: Ok if the the web and web api are hosted in different servers then, the relative url is not gonna work for you. so in addition to the option 1 you would have to update your ng binding to append the api url to the img src. With that said, to answer your first question .. yes create images folder under the web api project (that is if that is by design and you intended to do that)

Comment: Thanks a lot. At this stage i may not bother to understand the Pros / Cons of both solutions you said above but i am sticking to solution 1. i.e. Move images folder out of app_data. But i would appreciate if you can explain the second solution and update your answer. May be good for other readers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just drop everything except the file name if all your images are in the root of `Images`:

```
//using System.IO;

File.Path = Url.Content(string.Format("{0}/{1}", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images"), Path.GetFileName(fileName)));
```

> Update

should have been like Sam's answer:

```
File.Path = Url.Content(string.Format("~/App_Data/Images/{0}",Path.GetFileName(fileName)));
```

Comment: I did not get you much. Basically, my App_Data/Images folder is under Web Api project and Angular Client is under different project. Hope you understand what i am saying.

Comment: I guess I don't understand. If the file is uploaded to `AppData` this would work.

Comment: Isn't `Server.MapPath` supposed to give you the physical location? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @NikhilGirraj, yes, the main point of my answer was the `Path.GetFileName` part. I will update.